# error in graphql query importing in android java

Tags: graphql

The apolloclient dependency is added but the in the .graphql file the query not importing successfully it's showing the red error in the lines plugins are installed.please give a solution for this issue.i want this worked in java

i tried implementing the dependency and installed the graphql plugin